# SYSDATE - Timestamp to retrieve orders from last 2 minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, sysdate

This is used in a database package as a delay to pass data. The delay is 2 minutes so I need to only retrieve records if they've been in the database for 2 minutes or more.

This is what I have:

```
((SYSDATE - trunc(last_updated))*24*60) > l_delay_mins;
```

l_delay_mins = 2 minutes in this case.

However, the trunc cuts off the time and defaults to midnight, when the conversion is done it gives me the fraction of the day and then multiplies 24*60 which is always larger than 2, so the records aren't being delayed and are sending as soon as they arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `INTERVAL`:

```
where last_updated < systimestamp - (l_delay_mins * interval '1' minute);
```

Here is the same thing without `INTERVAL` but with a minute being a fraction of the day (kind of what you tried):

```
where last_updated < systimestamp - (l_delay_mins / 24 / 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor amendment to the above answer

Use `INTERVAL`:

```
where last_updated <= systimestamp - (l_delay_mins * interval '1' minute);
```